# Invalid argument when connecting to AF_UNIX socket in c++

Tags: c++, sockets

The following code compiles, but reports `Invalid argument` when it is executed:

```
int fd = socket (AF_UNIX, SOCK_SEQPACKET, 0);
if (fd == -1)
{
    cout << strerror (errno) << "\n";
    return;
}

struct sockaddr_un addr;
memset (&addr, 0, sizeof (addr));
addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
strcpy (addr.sun_path, "/path/to/socket");
if (connect (fd, (const struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof (addr) == -1))
{
    close (fd);
    cout << strerror (errno) << "\n";
    return;
}

close (fd);
```

The error happens when it tries to call `connect`. It does not give any indication as to which argument is invalid or why.

I have also tried using `SOCK_STREAM` when I create the socket, but it results in the same error.

Any idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 3):

The closing parenthesis on your `connect()` call is in the wrong place:

```
if (connect (fd, (const struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof (addr) == -1))
                                                                     ^
                                                                   wrong
```

This is causing you to pass an incorrect value to the `addrlen` parameter of `connect()` (ie, the result of evaluating the expression `sizeof(addr) == -1` instead of just the value of `sizeof(addr)`), hence the error.

This is also causing you to compare the return value of `connect()` incorrectly (ie, evaluating it as true/false instead of against -1).

You need to move the closing parenthesis to the correct place:

```
if (connect (fd, (const struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof (addr)) == -1)
                                                               ^
                                                            correct
```

Otherwise, break up the expressions into separate statements, eg:

```
int res = connect (fd, (const struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof (addr));
if (res == -1)
```